Creating log txt file
I am trying to create a log_file.txt in python.
SO, whenever I run the script each time it should generate new log file.
For example:
log_file
log_file1
log_file2
.
.
.
.
def log(message):
    try:
        counter = 1
        # Format the log message with current date and time
        log_message = f"[{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}] {message}\n"
        # Write the message to the log file
        with open("log_file.txt", "a") as log_file:
            log_file.write(log_message)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred while logging: {e}")

This is what I tried.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Your code is not going to work because you define the same filename and add new lines to it on every function call. (On a side note, the count variable is not used in your function).
Before writing data to a new log file, you need to check if there is a file in the same directory with the same name. If the directory already contains a file with the same name you're trying to give you need to add a suffix to the name.
To check filenames in the folder you can use glob
import glob
filenames = [file for file in glob.glob('/your_log_dir/*.txt')]


Have you tried using logging module with RotatingFileHandler??
I use below code as to most of my applications
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler 

logger = logging.Logger(__name__)

FORMAT = "[%(asctime)s:%(filename)s:%(lineno)s - function %(funcName)10s() -- %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, level=logging.INFO)
logging_filename = 'main.txt' #you can change file extension to other if you wish                                                                         
handler = RotatingFileHandler(logging_filename,
                            maxBytes=1000000,   # max file size
                            backupCount=10)     # file count

handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(FORMAT))                                                        
logger.addHandler(handler)           

                     

and in  sccript you use
message = f'this is my message{var1}, {var2}'
logger.info(message)

